# Hibernate replace null with ""

Tags: hibernate, replace, null

I am displaying values on my jsp page using hibernate . I have oracle database.
But if there is no value in any column in a table .so while displaying on jsp its displaying it as null.
I wanted to remove null and place "" in place of that. Do i need to do it something from hibernate ?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate have something like [Custom User Type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom-ut)

Here you have an example of getting name of enumeration an transform this name to enum: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypeForPersistingATypesafeEnumerationWithAVARCHARColumn

It's very easy to change this example to work with strings.

Answer (score 0):

compare value with !=null then assign empty;
ie.

```
      String value = value !=null ? value : "";
```